# Xcode Projects linking

Tags: xcode, macos, cocoa

I needed to make a project bundle with which has several small projects. When I try to add them into resources I get several errors. dont know where I am going wrong

Comment: Tip: When dragging sub-project files into the main project, make sure the sub-projects aren't open or they won't be available to edit (for some reason)

Comment: In my experience, Xcode 4 isn't super good (or successful) at embedding other projects (dependencies) into a parent project.  I solved the previous problems by using Xcode 3 to do the project embedding and then ran back to Xcode 4 and all was well.

Answer (score 0):

The feature is called *workspaces*. You have to create an Xcode workspace (there’s a special command in the File menu for it) and then you can drag other projects into the left project sidebar. I suggest that you google for some Xcode workspace tutorial to walk you through.